# Codepad/ideone style collaborative web IDE?

Tags: ide, collaboration, code-editor, codepad, online-compilation

I'm looking for a simple collaborative web-based text-editor which can compile—and show output from—a few popular languages such as: C++, PHP and Python.

### Research

#### Editors

- [Ace](http://ace.ajax.org)
- [EditArea](http://www.cdolivet.com/editarea) (people prefer Ace, e.g.: web2py and ideone moved to Ace)

#### IDE styled editors

- [AmyEditor](http://www.amyeditor.com)
- [Cloud9](https://c9.io)
- [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net)
- [Eclipse Orion](http://www.eclipse.org/orion)
- [ShiftEdit](http://shiftedit.net)

#### IDE styled editors which compile

- [CodeRun](http://www.coderun.com/ide) (supports C#, JavaScript and PHP)
- [Programr](http://www.programr.com) (supports Java [and Android!], C++, PHP, ASP.NET, C#, VB, Flex, Flash, iOS (UI, ObjetiveC), Processing, JavaScript [incl. JQuery and AJAX], Ruby, Python and even SQL [not sure for which DB].

#### Pastebins which compile

- [codepad](http://codepad.org)
- [IDEone](http://ideone.com) (IDEone uses Ace)

#### Collaborative code editors

- [collabedit](http://collabedit.com)
- [Etherpad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etherpad)

### Conclusion

I have been thus far unsuccessful at finding a syntax-highlighting, code revisioning, collaborative editing web-based IDE with a shared compile/interpret debug console.

Can you recommend one, preferably free? If there aren't any; I'll create then open-source a proof-of-concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Koding](https://koding.com/?c=ideh) provides an application with Collaboration for teams built in. Ontop of that, the you have full root access to your VM, so it supports any Linux tools that you want to install. Comes with all of the standard languages (Python, GoLang, Node, etc) as well :)

Comment: Hmm, not quite what I had in mind… however seems to tick all the boxes (and more). So thanks :D!

Answer (score 2):

[Cloud9 IDE](https://c9.io) has recently released a new collaborative tools including a new real-time collaborative editing (with authorship info), Group Chat and File Revision History timeslider. Further explained in https://c9.io/site/blog/2013/10/new-collaboration/

Mostafa,
The Cloud9 IDE Developer behind that release Collab

Comment: Very cool! - As far as I can tell though, it doesn't compile… yet!

Comment: Now it does compile. And I can't help but say it's really awesome: convenient, good-looking, with collaboration, terminal access, compilation, debugger, free accounts, many languages (bash, C++, python, php…), code snipets… Long live IDE9, ideal for discussing code with friends (I'm not affiliated with them).

Answer (score 0):

I've done some research into this for the purposes of teach ruby on rails, javascript/html, etc, and also for administering tech interviews where we want to see the candidate write code, run tests, and get things working while we observe the process.

Cloud9 is currently my favorite, as you can run fullstack rails apps, collabrate in the editor, run tests, group chat, etc. Its really powerful.

Thanks for compiling a great list!

Answer (score 0):

https://paiza.IO/ provides web-based online coding environments.

paiza.IO is focusing on making it easy to write and run code. You can write and run simple program like "Hello World" in 10 seconds just after opening the page.

paiza.IO have all the features you want, more or less:

- Syntax-highlighing(ACE based)
- Gist synchronization(for revisioning)
- Collaborate editing(TogetherJS based(so same as JsFiddle))
- Compiler and command stdout/stderr output tab.

Full-disclosure: I'm a developer of the https://paiza.IO/ .